# How to return a shuffled list considering mutually exclusive items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shuffle

Say I have a list of options and I want to pick a certain number randomly.

In my case, say the options are in a list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` and I want my script to return 3 elements.

However, there is also the case of two options that cannot appear at the same time. That is, if option 'a' is picked randomly, then option 'b' cannot be picked. And the same applies the other way round.

So valid outputs are: `['a', 'c', 'd']` or `['c', 'd', 'b']`, while things like <s>`['a', 'b', 'c']`</s> would not because they contain both 'a' and 'b'.

To fulfil these requirements, I am fetching 3 options plus another one to compensate a possible discard. Then, I keep a `set()` with the mutually exclusive condition and keep removing from it and check if both elements have been picked or not:

```
import random


mutually_exclusive = set({'a', 'b'})
options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
num_options_to_return = 3

shuffled_options = random.sample(options, num_options_to_return + 1)

elements_returned = 0
for item in shuffled_options:
    if elements_returned >= num_options_to_return:
        break

    if item in mutually_exclusive:
        mutually_exclusive.remove(item)
        if not mutually_exclusive:
            # if both elements have appeared, then the set is empty so we cannot return the current value
            continue

    print(item)
    elements_returned += 1
```

However, I may be overcoding and Python may have better ways to handle these requirements. Going through [`random`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) I couldn't find ways to do this out of the box. Is there a better solution than my current one?

Comment: Is the question specifically about choosing 3 from a list of 5, or do you need a generic solution for any N, K, and forbidden items?

Comment: @Roy2012 I am using 3 and 5 to simplify the problem and provide an easy example, although the heuristics is not going to be very complicated and won't consist in big lists. My real life problem will probably be picking 3 or 4 out of 9 with just two mutually exclusive.

Comment: if it's 3 or 4 out of 9, you can just create all the valid combinations upfront and pick one randomly. If it's 300-400 out of 900, well, that's a more challenging question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to create all of the possible results, filter out the invalid ones and make a [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) from that:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> from random import choice
>>> def is_valid(t):
...     return 'a' not in t or 'b' not in t
... 
>>> choice([
...     t 
...     for t in combinations('abcde', 3) 
...     if is_valid(t)
... ])
... 
('c', 'd', 'e')
```

Comment: Isn't this very very time consuming? However, the question is related to small lists, so it might be a good approach :)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco it could be, depends on the sizes of the inputs and how many combinations are valid.

Comment: Actually you are generating the entire list, you are not using a generator, so it only depends on the input size.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco generating the entire list *of valid combinations*, invalid ones are skipped from the iterator `itertools` provides.

Comment: But you generate every single combination before checking whether it's valid. Don't you? (I'm not saying this answer is bad, it's actually very elegant, just pointing out it might not scale with large input sizes)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco yes; I was confused by the "list" - that does iterate over all combinations even though not all end up in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit naive, but you could generate samples until your condition is met:

```
import random

options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
num_options_to_return = 3
mutually_exclusive = set({'a', 'b'})

while True:
    shuffled_options = random.sample(options, num_options_to_return)
    if all (item not in mutually_exclusive for item in shuffled_options):
        break

print(shuffled_options)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it with sets:

```
import random

mutually_exclusive = {'a', 'b'}
options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
num_options_to_return = 3

while True:
    s = random.sample(options, num_options_to_return)
    print('Sample is', s)
    if not mutually_exclusive.issubset(s):
        break
    print('Discard!')

print('Final sample:', s)
```

Prints (for example):

```
Sample is ['a', 'b', 'd']
Discard!
Sample is ['b', 'a', 'd']
Discard!
Sample is ['e', 'a', 'c']
Final sample: ['e', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: Good one! You can also check with [`ss.issubset(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Yep, this simplifies a code. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can restructure your options.

```
import random

options = [('a', 'b'), 'c', 'd', 'e']
n_options = 3

selected_option = random.sample(options, n_options)

result = [item if not isinstance(item, tuple) else random.choice(item)
          for item in selected_option]

print(result)
```

Comment: Good one, only that it has the flaw that 'a' and 'b' are less likely to appear. That is, the probability that either 'a' or 'b' will appear is equal to the probability of any other element to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I created the below function and I think it's worth sharing it too ;-)

```py
def random_picker(options, n, mutually_exclusives=None):
    if mutually_exclusives is None:
        return random.sample(options, n)
    elif any(len(pair) != 2 for pair in mutually_exclusives):
        raise ValueError('Lenght of pairs of mutually_exclusives iterable, must be 2')

    res = []
    while len(res) < n:
        item_index = random.randint(0, len(options) - 1)
        item = options[item_index]
        if any(item == exc and pair[-(i - 1)] in res for pair in mutually_exclusives
               for i, exc in enumerate(pair)):
            continue
        res.append(options.pop(item_index))
    return res
```

Where:

- `options` is the list of available options to pick from.
- `n` is the number of items you want to be picked from `options`
- `mutually_exclusives` is an iterable containing tuples pairs of mutually exclusive items

You can use it as follows:

```py
>>> random_picker(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 3)
['c', 'e', 'a']
>>> random_picker(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 3, [('a', 'b')])
['d', 'b', 'e']
>>> random_picker(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 3, [('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c')])
['e', 'd', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

l = [['a','b'], ['c'], ['d'], ['e']]
x = [random.choice(i) for i in random.sample(l,3)]
```

here `l` is a two-dimensional list, where the fist level reflects an `and` relation and the second level an `or` relation.